# Changing a flight date through a booking agency by going through the airline hack?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, bookings, tips-and-tricks

So I have to change my flight dates that I booked through an online travel agency. The flight isn't for another month.

The travel agency charges a lot of money for this and they also charge the airlines cost of changing a ticket + the price difference.

Is there a way I can by pass the travel agency, by getting my official flight information and requesting the airline to change it directly (this particular airline charges very little)?

I am worried that they will quote me a lot for the change on their part + they wont give me the best price on the airlines part.

Comment: Do you have ticket / reservation number? You should have received it after buyin the ticket. What airline this is?

Comment: @Kuba yes I have a reservation number

Answer (score 1):

Usually no.

The travel agent owns the ticket until it releases it to the airline when check in opens. Until this point is not possible for the airline to modify the ticket. [The issuing airline can prematurely take ownership of the ticket in some cases, but they won't do this unless they really have to.]

The travel agent should apply the change fee and the fare difference that the airline stipulates; *i.e.*, the same price should apply as did apply when going directly to the airline. However, the travel agent may also apply a service fee.